# Setting up a new Ubuntu Drive

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, 18.04

So, I have Windows on one SSD, and now I want to install Ubuntu on a different SSD and have them dual-boot. The problem is I don't know what size I should be making the partitions for `/root`, `/home` and `swap`, or if there are any other partitions I need to add.

It's a 120gb SSD, what should I be sizing these things at?

Comment: Unless you have specific reasons for separate partitions, simply use one big partition. There is no longer a separate swap partition in 18.04.

Comment: So make one big '/' partition? I don't need to make '/home' or '/boot'?

Comment: No, you don't. While installing, choose "Wipe the whole disk and install Ubuntu". Just make sure you choose the right disk, not the one that has Windows on it.